# in kivy not kivyMD i am in screen and i want get id the label from another screen

Tags: python, function, class, kivy, screen

Navigation and interaction between screens
in kivy not kivyMD i am in screen  fo add data and i want get id the label from another screen
for dsplaying the data, update the label Either on the whole screen or half of it is not a problem
The problem is taking data from one screen and displaying it on another screen

Comment: Please post a [mcve].